# How to continue after except?

Tags: python, networking, backend

I'm looping in range to check if all ports in a given IP input is open or not some ports socket library Do not recognize it so it gives me an error that the port not found ,

so I used try and exceptto change the error code but I cant continue to the next port and the script stops and cant use continue with except to skip that port and check the next one .

```
def all_ports():
    target = input('Type The IP : ')
    
    try:
        for port in range(1 , 65,536):
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.settimeout(1)
            r = s.connect_ex((target , port))

            if r == 0:
                service = socket.getservbyport(port)
                print(f'{port} is open !!!!!!!! ,  and service is {service}')
            else:
                service = socket.getservbyport(port)
                print(f'{port} is closed !!!! and service is {service}')
                s.close()
    except:
       print(f'we dont have port {port} in our system !')
```

Comment: why dont you move the try and except block inside the for loop

Comment: Can you post the error message before you used try and except?

Comment: I assume it only prints out the first port. If so what kinshukdua said should do the trick. Also welcome to SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may change the order of the `for` and the `try`, to wrap the exception handling around ONE socket connection only, not all, then you the code can resume when it fails for one port

```
def all_ports():
    target = input('Type The IP : ')
    for port in range(1, 65536):
        try:
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.settimeout(1)
            r = s.connect_ex((target, port))
            service = socket.getservbyport(port)
            if r == 0:
                print(f'{port} is open !!!!!!!! ,  and service is {service}')
            else:
                print(f'{port} is closed !!!! and service is {service}')
            s.close()
        except:
            print(f'We dont have port {port} in our system !')
```

Comment: thanks ! the whole thing was about to move try and except inside for loop so it will continue by for loop

Answer (score 0):

I would fix this by simply putting the try and except block inside the for loop.

For simplicity here is a simple example for both cases:

**Doesn't work**

```
item_list = [1, 2, 3, "a", 5]

try:
    for item in item_list:
        item += 1  # will give error for "a" as it is not a number
        print("item is:", item)
except:
    print("wrong input")
```

OUTPUT:

```
item is: 2
item is: 3
item is: 4
wrong input
```

To fix this:

**Works**

```
for item in item_list:
    try:
        item += 1
        print("item is:", item) 
    except:
        print("wrong input")
```

OUTPUT:

```
item is: 2
item is: 3
item is: 4
wrong input
item is: 6
```